# creating route table for private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create vpc with two subnets: one public with internet gateway and one private that can only communicate with other local resource.

i had no problem creating the public route table:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "HW2-public-crt" {
vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.hw2_vpc.id}"

route {
    //associated subnet can reach everywhere
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0" 
    //CRT uses this IGW to reach internet
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.hw2-igw.id}"
```

but when I tried to create the private route table:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "HW2-private-crt" {
vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.hw2_vpc.id}"
route {
cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
```

I get this error:

> "Error creating route: MissingParameter: The request must contain exactly one of gatewayId, natGatewayId, networkInterfaceId, vpcPeeringConnectionId, egressOnlyInternetGatewayId, transitGatewayId or instanceId
>   status code: 400"

when creating a route table in the console I don't see such requirement
any thoughts?

Comment: where is your gateway_id?

Comment: gateway_id - (Optional) Identifier of a VPC internet gateway or a virtual private gateway.
   
I don't want internet access, not sure what is virtual private gateway...

Comment: when I removed  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16" it let me complete the plan without errors...

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving the error because trying to create a route within the route table without telling it the route.

If you don't want to route outside the subnet:

> Note that the default route, mapping the VPC's CIDR block to "local", is created implicitly and cannot be specified.

If you do want to create a route outside of local:

The `route` argument (which is optional and why the command worked when you removed it) requires a `cidr_block` and one of the following:

- egress_only_gateway_id
- gateway_id
- instance_id
- nat_gateway_id
- network_interface_id
- transit_gateway_id
- vpc_peering_id

The list above is the path you'd be routed to when matching the cidr_block of the route.

**References**

[route_table](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route_table.html) .

Comment: If the subnet is entirely private and doesn't allow traffic beyond the VPC (ie not out to the internet via NAT or to any peered VPCs) the the route table can be completely empty. There is always a VPC local route on all route tables which doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I agree,  I'll add this to the answer.